# How to resolve the "Logging" security hotspot issue raised by Sonarqube? What is the best ways for logging without any security hotspot error?

Tags: python, logging, sonarqube

I am trying to write LOGS to the file using the logging module in python. When I ran the code through Sonarqube, it has shown me the following security hotspot error in terms of logging.

python code :

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.txt',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s")
```

For this type of logging declaration, the sonarqube is showing a log-injection.

What is the best practice of logging a package in python using Logging module within the norms of the Sonarqube rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a false positive. You can ask a question about it on [their community forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/), asking how this specific example is a log injection.

It is possible to have log injections, of course, but not in this vanilla example as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank You, Vinay for your swift reply.

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Security Hotspots are not immediate threats, but rather a warning for a developer to review potentially dangerous code.

> A Security Hotspot highlights a security-sensitive piece of code that the developer needs to review. Upon review, you'll either find there is no threat or you need to apply a fix to secure the code.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-hotspots/

As Vinay flagged, you can mark them as false positives, but sonar flags them for you to make sure that you understand the potential risk.